# C# MongoDB Bson Document не понимаю, как обратиться к полю в списке объекта

Tags: c#, mongodb

Я использую базу данных Mongo и работаю с Bson Document. В клиенте(WPF) у меня есть класс
Person, а у него внутри есть List из приглашений - invations, которые являются в свою очередь другим классом.В этом классе(Invation) есть поле InvationId - айди приглашения.    Так вот, я конвертирую объект класса Person в Bson Document и отправляю в базу данных.
Что мне нужно: пройтись по всем Person в базе данных, а в каждом Person пройтись по всем invation и проверить InvationId. Но проблема в том, что я не знаю, как это сделать -_- .
В клиенте это выглядело бы так: person.invations[i].login

1. Как пройтись по всем объектам в базе данных?
2. Как в каждом из них проверить Id объекта, который находится в списке?
   P.S я знаю, как обратиться к списку. Но не знаю, как обратиться к полю объекта в нем